# How to write tests against annotated parameters in an interface?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit

Is it possible to write a unit test to ensure that a method has a specific annotation attached to a specific parameter? In this case, can a unit test be written to make sure that `duplicate` has the annotation `@Validated` attached to the second parameter?

```
package com.myProject;

import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

public interface MyService {
    MyObj save(@Validated MyObj myObj);
    MyObj duplicate(MyObj toBeDuplicated, @Validated MyObj newValues);
}
```

Comment: @andrewdleach That question is about testing for annotations based on a field, and does not mention annotated parameters.